# Multiple master links on the same chain

Tags: chain, frugal, master-link

Not so long ago I put a new PYC SP1101 chain on my bike, but several rides in I managed to snap the rear derailleur off, which also bent a bunch of chain links. No way I'm throwing a perfectly good, albeit now shorter than needed chain away, so I decided to replace the bent section with leftovers lying around. The chain has hollow pins, so I can't just pop one out and push it back, that only leaves master links to connect the fragments, which I should have three of (all are the same, included with PYC SP1101).

Are there any potential downsides to multiple master links to be aware of?

Comment: I couldn't find any evidence against this practice and there are some valid use cases, like tandem chains. I'll attempt to do this regardless of answers, but this info might still be useful for whoever stumbles upon this Q/A.

Comment: You should probably avoid having master links closer together than about 10 links.

Comment: @DanielRHicks then I lucked out, I plan to cut off exactly 10 links. What's your statement based on, btw?

Comment: A quick link introduces slight irregularities in the "flow" of the chain.  Having such links close together creates more of a "rattle" or "ripple" in the chain motion and is more apt to produce shifting problems, etc.  Plus there will be more of a tendency for the chain to twist.

Comment: This is why you should always save the "offcut" from trimming a new chain to length.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing wrong with it other than aesthetics.

I have 3 master links on the 2.8 metre chain in my `bent.  Its glaringly obvious too cos the masters are shiny chrome and the rest of the chain is a dull cheap galv chain.

There might be a few grams difference in weight too, but realistically that's probably less than the weight of dirt on your bike.

Just use the same brand/style of master link, so you don't try and take one off the wrong way.

Comment: Nice point about the weight, I should totally measure the difference with my 1/100th gram scales.

Comment: @Klaster_1 make sure you report back

Comment: Seth made a video about master link chain: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1y95ztSY5U

Answer (score 4):

More than one master link should be fine.

The only issue I can see with this practice is having a few links of unworn chain inserted into a worn one which might cause problems - not a problem in your specific case as the chain is almost brand new.